# Force UpdatePanel.Update() from withing Shared Sub

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webmethod, subroutine

Is there any way to performe `UpdatePanel1.Update()` from within `Shared Sub`?

It get an error: `Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared sub ..`

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub DoSomeStuff(ByVal Param1 As String)

    // do some stuff and then update the updatepanel
    UpdatePanel1.Update() // not a valid code


End Sub
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: _No_. Not from a webmethod which is outside of a page's lifecycle. The controls simply doesn't exist on serverside at this time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - any work around?

Comment: Your code has `updatePanel` while your question is about `UpdatePanel1`. You might want to look into that.

Comment: @MrLister - just a dummy code.

Comment: So what you pasted here was not the actual code that produced the error?

Comment: @NewUser: Why do you use `UpdatePanels` **and** `Webmethods`? You could use an asynchronous postback to "do some stuff and then update the updatepanel".

Comment: @TimSchmelter - AFAIK asynchronous postback is just an update panel? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MrLister - this code is simplified version. Left only the relevant code.